# Is a svn propset still set on a svn export with --force flag option?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, svn-propset

Is a svn propset still set on a svn export? or does the export also remove any propset settings? To my understanding the export with the --force flag removes all the .svn directories but do the propset settings still apply?

Is there an option to keep and/or remove these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they're lost with all SVN related data.  If you're exporting, you're not creating a working copy.  Properties are just meta-data for Subversion to consume.  Properties don't make sense in the export scenario.